# SQL Left Join with null result return 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query like this

```
SELECT 
  a.STOCK_ITEM_NO, a.STOCK_BEG_QTY, b.DOUT_QTY_ISSUE 
FROM
  INV_STOCK AS a 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN INV_DOUT AS b 
    ON a.STOCK_ITEM_NO = b.DOUT_ITEM_NO 
WHERE a.STOCK_ITEM_NO = 'ABC01' 
  AND b.CREATEDDATE > '01-MAR-2016' 
  AND b.CREATEDDATE < '01-APR-2016'
```

There is `null` value when

```
select dout_qty_issue from inv_dout where b.CREATEDDATE > '01-MAR-2016' and b.CREATEDDATE < '01-APR-2016'
```

Because there is no data

So the result from the query is empty, as it fail to join (I think)
but can it return ?

```
'ABC01' | 10  | 0
```

Because now the query return

```
null | null| null
```

Comment: Cloud you please show two table structures.

Comment: Your `where` clause turns the `left join` into an `inner join`. Maybe you meant the `createddate` conditions as join conditions, rather than filter conditions.

Comment: @Mike it hasn't failed to join. Your `WHERE` criteria is on `INV_DOUT` table columns and since there is no data for that date range, that is why you will not get results. You need to re-structure your `WHERE` criteria.

Comment: INV_STOCK
STOCK_ITEM_NO nvarchar(20), STOCK_BEG_QTY decimal(14,2)
INV_DOUT
DOUT_ITEM_NO nvarchar(20), DOUT_QTY_ISSUE decimal(14,2), CREATEDDATE datetime

Comment: yeah, can if there's nothing to join field dout_qty_issue return 0 value?

Comment: @Mike See my update, if there's nothing to join field dout_qty_issue it would return 0 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your date WHERE statement inside the LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT a.STOCK_ITEM_NO,a.STOCK_BEG_QTY, b.DOUT_QTY_ISSUE
FROM INV_STOCK a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN INV_DOUT b ON a.STOCK_ITEM_NO = b.DOUT_ITEM_NO 
AND b.CREATEDDATE BETWEEN '01-MAR-2016' AND '01-APR-2016'
WHERE a.STOCK_ITEM_NO = 'ABC01'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT a.STOCK_ITEM_NO
      ,a.STOCK_BEG_QTY
      ,ISNULL(b.DOUT_QTY_ISSUE,0) as DOUT_QTY_ISSUE
FROM INV_STOCK AS a
LEFT JOIN INV_DOUT AS b
    ON a.STOCK_ITEM_NO = b.DOUT_ITEM_NO
       AND b.CREATEDDATE > '01-MAR-2016'
       AND b.CREATEDDATE < '01-APR-2016'
WHERE a.STOCK_ITEM_NO = 'ABC01'
```

Put the where condition to Join, you can display what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Move the filtration of left joined table from `WHERE` to `ON` clause.

```
SELECT a.STOCK_ITEM_NO, a.STOCK_BEG_QTY, ISNULL(b.DOUT_QTY_ISSUE,0) DOUT_QTY_ISSUE
FROM
  INV_STOCK AS a 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN INV_DOUT AS b 
    ON a.STOCK_ITEM_NO = b.DOUT_ITEM_NO 
     AND b.CREATEDDATE > '01-MAR-2016' 
     AND b.CREATEDDATE < '01-APR-2016' 
WHERE a.STOCK_ITEM_NO = 'ABC01'
```